# Simple Rock-Paper-Scissors to get more comfortable with OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented, rock-paper-scissors

I'm trying to get a little more comfortable with using classes as they're meant to be used, instead of using them to decorate my code to make it look more legitimate. Can you see anything glaringly wrong/could be improved/possibly different implementations?

```
import random

class Player(object):

    def __init__(self,player):
        self.name = player
        self.score = 0
        self.choice = []

class Game(object):

    player_one,player_two = Player('player_one'),Player('player_two')

    def gameplay(self):
        choices = ['rock','paper','scissors']
        self.player_one.choice,self.player_two.choice = random.choice(choices),random.choice(choices)
        if self.player_one.choice == self.player_two.choice:
            print 'Tie!'
        elif self.player_one.choice == 'rock' and self.player_two.choice == 'paper':
            print '{0} is the winner with {1}!'.format(self.player_one.name,self.player_one.choice)
            self.player_one.score += 1
        elif self.player_one.choice == 'paper' and self.player_two.choice == 'rock':
            print '{0} is the winner with {1}!'.format(self.player_two.name,self.player_two.choice)
            self.player_two.score += 1
        elif self.player_one.choice == 'scissors' and self.player_two.choice == 'rock':
            self.player_two.score += 1
        elif self.player_one.choice == 'scissors' and self.player_two.choice == 'paper':
            self.player_one.score += 1
        elif self.player_one.choice == 'paper' and self.player_two.choice == 'scissors':
            self.player_two.score += 1
        elif self.player_one.choice == 'rock' and self.player_two.choice == 'scissors':
            self.player_one.score += 1
        print '{0}\'s score is {1}, and {2}\'s score is {3}'.format(self.player_one.name,self.player_one.score,self.player_two.name,self.player_two.score)


g = Game()
for i in range(0,10000):
    g.gameplay()
```

Comment: I have rolled back the last edit. Please see *[What to do when someone answers](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)*.

Comment: oops, my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that one another class Choice will be useful. You have two functionality to move to this class:

- make random choice. You can simple write `def make_random(self):`
- compare two choices. You can define standard operators `def __lt__(self, oth):` and `def __gt__(self, oth):`. If you want handle ties than `__eq__` operator will be useful also.

Then your gameplay function could be like

```
def gameplay(self):
    self.player_one.choice.make_random()
    self.player_two.choice.make_random()
    if self.player_one.choice > self.player_two.choice:
        self.player_one.score += 1
    elif self.player_one.choice < self.player_two.choice:
        self.player_two.score += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Having `choice` a member of `Player` is a doubtful decision. The player is not interested in it at all - the choice is produced and forgotten. It is `Game` that uses it. On the other hand, `Player` may benefit from the `play()` method returning a choice:

```
    def gameplay(self):
        choice1 = player1.play()
        choice2 = player2.play()
        decide_winner(choice1, choice2)
        ....
```

Supporting a human, or AI, or any other play strategy, becomes trivial.